Tinymce not working with php while using require or include in the php file
mydb_config.php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "my_username";
$password = "my_passowrd";

try {
  $my_all_db_connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=my_all_db", $username, $password,array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $my_all_db_connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
?>

my_tinymce_form.php
<?php include 'mydb_config.php'; ?>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/1pmtkloiucs7gc1zvrc5fqwz5vbloi3cjpbvu85a0y1f49bc4s5v0/tinymce/7/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>

<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: 'anchor autolink charmap codesample emoticons image link lists media searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount checklist mediaembed casechange export formatpainter pageembed linkchecker a11ychecker tinymcespellchecker permanentpen powerpaste advtable advcode editimage advtemplate ai mentions tinycomments tableofcontents footnotes mergetags autocorrect typography inlinecss markdown',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image media table mergetags | addcomment showcomments | spellcheckdialog a11ycheck typography | align lineheight | checklist numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat',
    tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
    tinycomments_author: 'Author name',

  automatic_uploads: true,
  images_upload_url: 'extra_scripts/tinymce_image_uploader.php',
  images_reuse_filename: true,

    mergetags_list: [
      { value: 'First.Name', title: 'First Name' },
      { value: 'Email', title: 'Email' },
    ],
    ai_request: (request, respondWith) => respondWith.string(() => Promise.reject("See docs to implement AI Assistant")),
  });

  tinymce.activeEditor.uploadImages().then(() => {
  document.forms[0].submit();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" style="height: 150px;" name="textarea"></textarea>
</body>

Tinymce works fine if i remove the first line ie. "include 'mydb_config.php';". at the same time if i put 'mydb_config.php' files codes directly in 'my_tinymce_form.php' it works fine. but tinymce not working while using "include 'mydb_config.php';". anybody help me out to find the reason behind this. what is wrong with include in this case.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?

Do you get any valid HTML code in your browser? What does the generated HTML code looks like?

@Progman yes getting full valid HTML code. but tinymce not applied on textarea while using "include" or "require_once".  at the same time if i put php code (i.e, include file codes) directly in the page, tinymce works fine.

Since PHP is running on the server and TinyMCE is running in the browser, any PHP code is unrelated to the problem. Check the generate HTML code and check the javascript console for any errors.

@Progman. yes i understood you. but there is no errors in javascript console.

What happens in case you include the file? How does the generated markup look like?
